# Want to show a 3D animation in HTML5 that supports webworks that uses webkit

Tags: html, blackberry-webworks, html5-animation

I want to use a 3d sort of simple animation like throwing a 3d football on a certain surface but I also want it to support webworks that uses webkit, and I think webkit doesn't support 3D webGL. So what should I do?

I have the option of an animated GIF or I need to use a sprite of 3D images and use that, or is there any framework that can help me to achieve that?

Whether I use an animated GIF or 3D image sprite, will I need to make a sprite of the canvas or just of one object and what is the best way to use such a sprite?

Comment: This isn't really a proper answer, but just to give you a little bit more info - as of very recently, the latest version of Chrome supports WebGL out of the box (see [link](http://www.thinq.co.uk/2011/2/4/chrome-9-brings-webgl-support-chrome-instant/)). Also, WebGL is supported by the nightly build of Webkit -  but I think you need to be running Snow Leopard and specifically enable it by writing a property value (see [link](http://www.ikriz.nl/2010/12/12/enable-webgl-in-safari/)). I presume you would need wider support than this?

Comment: thanks for your help, and I have also seen some frameworks like Raphael.js and processing.js so if in future I will need to do some animation then where webGL will not be supported, I think a simple solution can be sprite of images also.

Comment: Dropped the WebWork tag, since the tag is related to the Java framework from OpenSymphony and not what you are referring to.

Comment: The English language needs articles in front of nouns!